# Android Restart App but has wwhite screen 100ms

Tags: java, android

Android Restart App but has white screen 100ms. How to fix it?

My restart App Code

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplication().getPackageName());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The white screen is the default background of android activity. If u dont wish to see it... Go in styles.xml and create a theme with android:windowsBackground set as the background which you want. And den set this theme for your activity